# Is a particle track in a bubble chamber an example of the quantum Zeno effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, measurements

The [quantum Zeno effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Zeno_effect) describes the rapid subsequent measurements on a quantum state to which a system has collapsed after the first measurement. If the measurements are made one after another fast enough, the state has no time to evolve significantly and the measurements keep the state steady. Which is quite unexpected as you would think that the more you measure the more is changed.

Now consider a particle making it's way through a bubble chamber. There is a smooth trail of bubbles to be seen and the particle seems in a steady state over time. The momentum seems constant and the position doesn't seem to spread out.

Is this a quantum Zeno effect?

Comment: It's considered a Mott problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem

Comment: [Related, possible duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/649246/44126).

Answer (score 2):

No.  The quantum nature is lost. Each little bubble translated quantum mechanically is innumerable electromagnetic  quantum interactions of the molecules on the way of the elementary particle, with which the particle interacts sequentially. Remember  [Avogadro's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), the number of particles in a mole, is $6.02214076×10^{23}$ .